# Virtuemart language files

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

As i understood most of language files are in `/languages` and `/administrator/languages`, but i cannot find few lines of text in those files for Virtuemart2.
Please help me locate those.

Here is the [pic](http://firepic.org/?v=4.2013-07-23_w2vkb8j8nylw.png) of what i need to translate to another language.
Sorry the text there is in Russian. This is a part of the page which is output by `order_done.php` layout of virtuemart2 views, this is the line that outputs the three lines of code I underlined.

```
echo $this->html;
```

in a `view.html.php` I found how html property is formed

```
private function lOrderDone() {
        $html = JRequest::getVar('html', JText::_('COM_VIRTUEMART_ORDER_PROCESSED'), 'default', 'STRING', JREQUEST_ALLOWRAW);
        $this->assignRef('html', $html);

        //Show Thank you page or error due payment plugins like paypal express
    }
```

But i cannot find where exatctly all the text is formed, so that i can see which constants to search. Maybe someone knows? Beforehand thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for this file:

```
language\en-GB\en-GB.com_virtuemart.ini
```

**Line 282**

```
COM_VIRTUEMART_ORDER_PROCESSED="Your order has been processed."
```

Note: For RU you need to download the language file for virtuemart.

**Update:**

All language files related with virtuemart (en-GB example)

-Backoffice

```
administrator\language\en-GB\en-GB.com_virtuemart.ini
administrator\language\en-GB\en-GB.com_virtuemart.menu.ini
administrator\language\en-GB\en-GB.com_virtuemart.sys.ini
administrator\language\en-GB\en-GB.com_virtuemart_countries.ini
administrator\language\en-GB\en-GB.com_virtuemart_media.ini
```

-Frontoffice

```
language\en-GB\en-GB.com_virtuemart.ini
language\en-GB\en-GB.com_virtuemart.sef.ini
language\en-GB\en-GB.com_virtuemart.sys.ini
language\en-GB\en-GB.mod_virtuemart_product.ini
```

Comment: Well on the pic that i gave link to in my question, i've underlined the text i need. The one you mean (first 2 lines of text on the page) i found in language\ru-Ru\ru-Ru.com_virtuemart.ini (russian version), the constant COM_VIRTUEMART_CART_THANKYOU
So i need the next 3 lines:
i believe in english they should state something like:
1) Method of Payment
2) Order number
3) currency title in my case "л" in us will be "USD" or "$"
So these three i cannot find.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but i've doublechecked, there are about 4 different language constants with the same value (e.g. "Order number") both in backend and frontend(in the files en-GB.com_virtuemart.ini) , but changing those had not changed the text on the order page.

Comment: @EliasMamo maybe override the token in backoffice. Language manager-> Overrides. Also, clean the cache anyway.

Comment: Found two of the constants in Vmpayment plugin
/administrator/language/plg.vmpayment_standard
(i think exact language file will depend on payment method)
the text i needed to fix was in 
VMPAYMENT_STANDARD_PAYMENT_INFO
VMPAYMENT_STANDARD_ORDER_NUMBER
but could not find the currency tag text constant there, anyone can help?

Comment: I wish i knew what the token for this particular currency tag is

Comment: @EliasMamo, in Language manager-> Overrides ->new you have the search engine for tokens and values.

Comment: Ive searched there, and it doesnt seem to be the one, ive tried modifying it and it didnt change the page output